# Change listing number separator

Tags: listings, numbering

I am working with the [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings) and trying to change the separator from the default period to a hyphen. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to.

I tried the code snippet below, but it doesn't appear to be working.

`\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thechapter-\arabic{lstlisting}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=The Listing Caption, language=xml]
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
 <data>
    <format/>
 </data>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\thelstlisting` macro is defined via the `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

You can either re-define it after `\begin{document}`, or use the `\AtBeginDocument` hook yourself (recommended).

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\thelstlisting}{\thechapter-\arabic{lstlisting}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=The Listing Caption, language=xml]
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
 <data>
    <format/>
 </data>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]